# Problema con angular en recibir dos objetos

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Recientemente empece de practicas dual en una empresa que usan angular para el desarrollo de Web.

Me han mandado una tarea que llevo varios dias intentando resolver, muchos de aquí le resultará alguna tontería pero para mí me está costando la vida.

Consiste en en pintar algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que va a recibir dos objetos del siguiente tipo:

const ordersTotal ={
amount: 1400000,
total: 100
}

const ordersPndingTotals = {
amount: 1200000,
total: 10
}

y llamaremos al component asi:

<app-orders-totals [orders]="ordersTotal", [pendings]="ordersPndingTotals" ><...>

Por ahora esto es lo que tengo hecho

En el app.component.html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el app.component.ts
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el card-sample.component.ts
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: `[orders]="ordersTotal", [pendings]` esa coma está de más

Answer (score 1):

No usar fotos para código tenes un buen editor para escribirlo
Para la comunicación entre componentes Tenes este buen tutorial [comunicación entre componentes](https://academia-binaria.com/flujo-de-datos-entre-componentes-angular/)
La forma en que lo haces es incorrecta ya que el hijo puede recibir valores desde el padre para mostrarlos  vía html pero no como lo planteaste  el código que definís no es accesible y la coma como te comentaron no se debe especificar  El @Input de Angular se pone en el componente hijo para indicar que esas variables proviene desde fuera del componente y para que tenga sentido que sea el hijo quien las represente hay que darle valores en el padre o tambien modificar a  esos valores en el hijo de acuerdo a lo que se requiera es una forma que permite la comunicación entre componentes estableciendo la responsabilidad de cada uno de ellos

```js
// componente padre
export class AppComponent {
  
  ordersPendingTotal!: { amount: number; total: number; };
  ordersTotal!: { amount: number; total: number; };
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ordersTotal ={ amount: 1400000, total: 100 }

    this.ordersPendingTotal = { amount: 1200000, total: 10 }
  }
}
// componente hijo 
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() orders!: { amount: number; total: number; }
  @Input() pendings!: { amount: number; total: number; };
  
  
  constructor() { }
  }
```

```html
<!-- vista del padre-->
<h1>Mostrame la vista desde el hijo</h1>
  <app-child [orders]="ordersTotal" [pendings]="ordersPendingTotal"></app-child
  <!--orders y pendings es lo que mostrara el hijo
  recibe desde el padre ordersTotal y ordersPendingTotal
  -->
  <!-- vista desde el hijo-->
  
  <h1>Orders</h1>

<h2>Total:{{orders.amount}}</h2>
<h4>{{orders.total}}</h4>
<h2>Pending:{{pendings.amount}}</h2>
<h4>{{pendings.total}}</h4>
```